# List all posts in alphabetical order on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Does anyone know how I can make a list of all my posts available in alphabetical order in Tumblr?

Comment: Do all of your posts have titles? Could you maybe post a link?

Comment: yes they have titles and no I can't link it cause it's an adult blog

Comment: I just want to make a page that will list all my text posts in alphabetical order. Kind of like a glossary. I'm not really a programmer so I don't know how to use API

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by via the Tumblr API, as it does provide the ability to request the Text posts for a blog and return the results as JSON-encoded objects. You can then use code to sort these results alphabetically.

Tumblr API Details - www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

**Text Posts**

```
Response Field  Type    Description
title          String   The optional title of the post
body           String   The full post body
```

Here is an example of a request and what you will get in the response - http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/citriccomics.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4

You can get a better look at what this all means (i.e. each separate post) by using this online JSON viewer - http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/citriccomics.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4

Making this happen would not be too difficult for a PHP or web programmer.

Comment: Saw the same thing! I know the start would be `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts/text?api_key={key}&[optional-params=]` but given what the OP wrote I was thinking there'd have to be some sort of boolean to filter for only posts with titles...

Comment: The OP said they all have titles, so no issue there, he could easily do the sort he required. And should a post have a null title, you could programatically remove that from the sort or place it at the end of the list.

Comment: True- forgot he had titles for all. I was just tooling around with it on my own tumblr where I don't and forgot.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so can anyone please give me an example html/php/tumblr code?